# Is it possible to change what variable is being affected by a line of code depending on another variable?

Tags: swift

So I'm learning Swift in a school course and I am pretty new to it. I have to create an app that allows the user to enter in several different numbers(about 10-20) into different text fields. Once they do I want to be able to assign each of those text fields to a corresponding variable (ie num1 = num1text.text, num2 = num2text.text). As far as I know I would have to write out a line of code for each text field assigning it to each variable. What I'm wondering is whether its possible to do something like \() to change the number so that I could run the same function but each time it would only be a different var and textfield

essential I dont want to do this

```
var income1:Double = 0
var income2:Double = 0

func numset(){
income1 = income1text.text
income2 = income2text.text
}
```

I want to do something that would have an effect like this (I know this doesnt work)

```
var income1:Double = 0
var income2:Double = 0

func numset(){
num = num+1
income\(num) = income\(num)text.text
}
```

```
var income1:Double = 0
var income2:Double = 0

func numset(){
num = num+1
income\(num) = income\(num)text.text
}
```

I tried this but \() cant be used outside of strings

Comment: This is what arrays and `@IBOutletCollection` are for.

Comment: Yes, an array is appropriate here. But I'd like to point out that this is a really interesting perspective on language design that someone like me who started out with older languages, when string interpolation didn't really exist, would never have thought of!

Comment: I’m not sure I’m understanding your question correctly but I think in general terms what you want is an array (to store any amount of incomes) and then a for loop running over that array, or adding stuff to it etc.

Comment: @HangarRash I'm not quite sure how arrays work. Could you explain how I could use one in this situation?

Comment: In a compiled language it's basically impossible to compose variable names at runtime because they are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @LF Please see the [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) chapter of the [Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/) - along with the rest of the book.